# Multiple stores using multidomain SSL certificate

Tags: multistore, ssl, multidomain, magento-2.1.8

I have an issue with child stores in my multi store environment when using the multidomain certificate. Basically, the child stores are pointing to the main website (but keeping the url which causes cross-domain issues).

I'm hoping I have missed a step in the setup of the other stores, but I can't see what.

I am using cPanel & Engintron.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue, I resolved it by adding virtual host entries to httpd.conf. Basically, I found the entry for the primary domain and copied it, replacing the domain name with the child domain name (for each child) and keeping the same certificate.

After saving, restart httpd service.